# Where to find Shopify Collection page SEO data section?

Tags: seo, local-seo, shopify

I am just a beginner at Shopify. I want to change the main collection page's SEO data. I check for pages but I couldn't find out. Check with theme customization and nothing found related to SEO. Where it is located? How can I find out the Collection landing page?